# Strange program behaviour after closing a Linux socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm studying Linux/UNIX sockets, so I wrote a very simple "game" based on it, called "21 matches". There's a heap that consists of 21 matches, and each player takes one, two or three matches from it. The person who takes the last match loses the game.

Obviously, the key to winning is to complement your opponent's turn up to 4 matches, so he has to take the very last match (works only if you do the first turn). So, client connects to the server and "plays" against the server till he loses. There can be more than one client connected, so I limit the number of connection, making my host reject any further ones.

The only thing I can't fix or explain is that when someone's getting rejected, the very first client loses the game *immediately*, even if he hasn't made any turns. This might be explained if I let the new client touch any client's heap, but I don't! I also tracked the buffer array, but it doesn't get harmed in any way.

Here's the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void die (const char *s, int errcode);
int mkservsock();
void acceptclient();
void dropclient (int client);
void make_turn (int client);

enum
{
  port   = 3333,
  buf_s  = 100,
  limit  = 3
};

void die (const char *s, int errcode)
{
  perror (s);
  exit (errcode);
}

struct pollfd fds[limit + 1];  // client socket descriptors array
int left[limit + 1];           // how many matches left
int nfd = 1;                   // number of the next client
char buffer[buf_s];            // buffer for communicating

// creates a single socket to poll
int mkservsock()
{
  int s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons (port);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  if (bind (s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
    die ("Can't bind socket", 1);

  if (listen (s, 1) == -1)
    die ("Can't start listening", 1);

  return s;
}

// adds new client to descriptors array or rejects it, if number of connections exceeds the limit
void acceptclient()
{
  int c = accept (fds[0].fd, 0, 0);
  fds[nfd].fd = c;
  fds[nfd].events = POLLIN;
  if (nfd == limit + 1)
  {
    sprintf (buffer, "Server is busy, try again later\n");
    send (fds[nfd].fd, buffer, strlen (buffer), 0);
    close (fds[nfd].fd);
    return;
  } else
  {
    left[nfd] = 21;
    sprintf (buffer, "Matches available: %d\nTake 1, 2 or 3!\n", left[nfd]);
    send (fds[nfd].fd, buffer, strlen (buffer), 0);
    nfd++;
  }
}

// disconnects a client in case of match ending or inappropriate data sent
void dropclient (int client)
{
  int i, j;
  close (fds[client].fd);
  for (i = client; i < nfd - 1; i++)
  {
    fds[i] = fds[i + 1];
    left[i] = left[i + 1];
  }
  nfd--;
}


void make_turn (int client)
{
  int n = recv (fds[client].fd, buffer, buf_s, 0);
  if (n == 0) {
    dropclient (client);
    return;

  } else if (n > 3)
  {
    // input counts as incorrect if it contains more than 1 symbol,
    // since we expect a single digit and nothing else
    // (yep, we get two extra bytes when receiving a message)
    sprintf (buffer, "I can break rules, too. Goodbye.\n");
    send (fds[client].fd, buffer, strlen (buffer), 0);
    dropclient (client);
    return;
  }

  // way to extract a digit from the character
  int received = buffer[0] - '0';  
  if (received > 3 || received <= 0)
  {
    sprintf (buffer, "You're allowed to take 1, 2 or 3 matches only\n");
    send (fds[client].fd, buffer, strlen (buffer), 0);
    return;

  } else if (received > left[client])
  {
    sprintf (buffer, "You can't take more than %d\n", left[client]);
    send (fds[client].fd, buffer, strlen (buffer), 0);
    return;

  } else  
  {
    // obviously, it happens only when there's the only match,
    // and the client has to take it
    if (left[client] == received)
    {
      sprintf (buffer, "You lost!\n");
      send (fds[client].fd, buffer, strlen (buffer), 0);
      dropclient (client);
      return;

    } else
    {
      // sort of "keeping the game up"
      left[client] -= 4;
      sprintf (buffer, "Matches left: %d (I took %d)\n", left[client], 4 - received);
      send (fds[client].fd, buffer, strlen (buffer), 0);
      return;
    }  
  }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  fds[0].fd = mkservsock ();
  fds[0].events = POLLIN;

  for (;;)
  {
    int status, i;
    status = poll (fds, nfd, -1);
    if (status == -1)
      die ("Error while polling", 1);

    if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN)
      acceptclient();

    for (i = 1; i < nfd; i++)
    {
      if (fds[i].revents & POLLERR)
      {
        printf ("Got troubles on %d\n", i);
        continue;
      }

      if (fds[i].revents & POLLIN)
        make_turn (i);
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the thing happening to the first client after reaching max. number of connections:

```
Matches available: 21
Take 1, 2 or 3!
```

*(don't take anything, meanwhile someone connects and gets rejected)*

*(after this, post any number and it'll say that there's only one match in the heap)*

```
1
You lost!
```

Note that you lose if and **only** if your input is equal to a number of matches left. So, what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure you're writing C++?

Comment: C or C++, it doesn't matter much in this question. Anyway, changing label to C and cleaning up this code to prevent misleading

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger, line by line, to see what happens in this case?

Comment: Yep, got nothing (maybe I'm looking for the wrong thing).

Comment: @user1823304: Of course it matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite `left[]`, when you call `acceptclient()` and don't check if there's room in `fds` to store the new connection.

You first initialize the new client `fds` and afterwards reject the connection, but then it is too late, because you have written one entry beyond the array. And beyond the array, there's the `left[]` array, which now has a 1 or 0 stored in it. So, no matter how the first client responds, he always takes the last.

Comment: No, I do owerwrite it only when there's enough room for a new client, otherwise a new person gets kicked off.

Comment: Yes but you first store the `c` in `fds[nfd]`, which is already one entry beyond. You must first check the number of clients and reject or reserve one more space in `fds`, which would be `fds[limit + 2]`.

Comment: That's what was wrong! Man, you saved me a good load of time.